# infinite for loop with correct limits

Tags: c++, infinite-loop

can you please explain why this code is going in infinite loop? I am unable to find the error. It is working fine with small values of n and m.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    long long n=1000000, m=1000000;
    long long k = 1;

    for (long long i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (long long j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            k++;
        }

    }

    cout << k;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you think it's infinite? How long did you wait? (1000000000000 nanoseconds is slightly less than 17 minutes.)

Comment: Are you compiling with optimizations? Either your compiler is smart enough to remove the nested loop or it will take quite a long time to finish. Also, given some of the hints (usual suspects) in the posted code, I'd guess you are trying to implement the wrong algorithm.

Comment: That's exactly why it works well with small n and m values

Comment: Add some code to print the value of `i` inside the loop every 100,000 iterations or so.

Comment: Performant code that does the same: `k = m * n;`. But probably not what you're looking for ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when I Run this code I got this as my output

```
1000000000001
```

*reference : I had run this code in the code chef IDE(https://www.codechef.com/ide)
you can try in this IDE once, I guess there is some problem with your IDE
or might be some other issue*

it took me less than 20 sec to run this(on clock)

But when I put the same code in CODE::BLOCKS its taking long time(like you said infinite loops running) and the reason is quite simple it should do 1000000000000 runs

however this brings me a questions what's difference between code chef IDE and code::blocks compiler
(Got a New question from your question ([Difference Between Code-Chef IDE and Code::Blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66814416/difference-between-code-chef-ide-and-codeblocks)))

***Finally answer is try on with code chef IDE that's it , this code runs fast there***

Hope this Helps you

Answer (score 1):

It's not infinite, but that `k++` operation has to run for `1,000,000 * 1,000,000 = 1,000,000,000,000` times. It's not infinite, but it takes too long. That's exactly why it works well with small n and m values.

Answer (score 1):

It is a typical target for optimization.

1. Build with -Ofast.

```
g++ t_duration.cpp -Ofast -std=c++11 -o a_fast

#time ./a_fast
1000000000001
real    0m0.002s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.002s
```

it takes almost no time to return the output.

2. Build with -O1.

```
 g++ t_duration.cpp -O1 -std=c++11 -o a_1


 #./a_1
419774 ms
```

About 420 seconds to complete the calculation.